# modification of the content on a specific column in mysql. better in a single update?

Tags: mysql, sql

The name of the card "Rascals" (line 55 of the excel) it will be modified by "Hal Roach's Rascals", and the rerity "Common" it will be "Proletari"

```
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Carta;

    CREATE TABLE Cards(
        id_carta VARCHAR(255),
        name VARCHAR(255),
        rarity VARCHAR(255),
        deck VARCHAR(255),
        player VARCHAR(255),
        level VARCHAR(255), 
        PRIMARY KEY(id_carta),
        FOREIGN KEY(rarity)REFERENCES Rarity(id_rarity),
        FOREIGN KEY(deck)REFERENCES Deck(id_deck),
    );
```

[image]

My code is:

```
    UPDATE cards SET cards_name = 'Hal Roachs Rascals'  WHERE cards_name = 'Rascals';
    UPDATE cards_rarity = 'Proletari' WHERE  cards_rarity = 'Common;
```

My question is if it is correct or it could be do it in a single update?

Comment: `UPDATE cards_rarity = 'Proletari' WHERE cards_rarity = 'Common;` isn't valid syntax, can you clarify what you're actually using?

Comment: Excel <> MySQL. Anyway, in theory you could combine multiple updates into a single using complex logic. However, it's just simple and cleaner to do two separate ones.

Comment: 1. Do you want to update only record of `Rascals` OR want to do `1` & replace `Common` in all the records?

Comment: Yes ,you are alright,my mistake,it would be:UPDATE cards SET  cards_rarity = 'Proletari' WHERE  cards_rarity = 'Common;

Comment: Sorry I will try to explain me better,when the name of a card be like "RASCALS" I must change that name with "Hal Ro..." and then change only the rarity of this card  not all the cards which have "common" rarity.More clear? @जलजनक

Comment: Alright, you share inconsistent table-schema & queries, Table & Column names don't match. There is also, `Rarity` table.

Comment: Typically if you're going to make 2 updates that do not have any relation (aka. you're updating set of cards with name 'Rascals' and another set of cards with rarity 'Common'), it doesn't typically make sense to try to do those operations with one update.

Answer (score 0):

"when the name of a card is like "RASCALS" I must change that name with "Hal Ro..." and then change only the rarity of this card not all the cards which have "common" rarity"
It is like that:
UPDATE cards SET cards_name = 'Hal Roachs Rascals' AND cards_rarity=’Proletari’ WHERE cards_name = 'Rascals';  ???